# Al momento de sumar dos variables float me sale un resultado diferente

Tags: java

```
//Esto es un JFrame de un botón en NetBeans 8.2

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        short comensales;
        float precio_arroz, precio_gambas, cant_arroz, cant_gambas, coste_arroz, coste_gambas, coste_total;
        comensales = Short.parseShort(txtcomensales.getText());
        precio_arroz = Float.parseFloat(txtprecio_arroz.getText());
        precio_gambas = Float.parseFloat(txtprecio_gambas.getText());
        cant_arroz = (float) (comensales * 0.5 / 4);
        cant_gambas = (float) (comensales * 0.25 / 4);
        coste_arroz = cant_arroz * precio_arroz;
        coste_gambas = cant_gambas * precio_gambas;
        coste_total = coste_arroz + coste_gambas;
        txtcant_arroz.setText(String.valueOf(cant_arroz + " kg"));
        txtcant_gambas.setText(String.valueOf(cant_gambas + " kg"));
        txtcoste_arroz.setText(String.valueOf(coste_arroz + " soles"));
        txtcoste_gambas.setText(String.valueOf(coste_arroz + " soles"));
        txtcoste_total.setText(String.valueOf(coste_total + " soles"));
    }
```

Cuando se opera en coste_total = coste_arroz + coste_gramos sale un número diferente, como ejemplo suma 1.5 más 1.5 y sale 4.875, realmente no sé qué está mal.

[image]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice lo mismo que tenes pero con javascript, esta correcto el resultado de 4.875, lo que falla en el codigo es que la penultima linea de `txtcoste_gambas.setText(String.valueOf(coste_arroz + " soles"));` tenes justamente el valor del arroz, por eso vez que el arroz es 1.5 y las gambas es 1.5 en pantalla, pero la suma interna toma el valor de 3.375 (gambas).

```
txtcoste_gambas.setText(String.valueOf(coste_gambas + " soles"));
```

reemplazandola con esa linea deberia estar funcionando bien. Es un simple error que siempre pasa solo hay que estar mas atento y hacer a mano el procedimeinto para calcular bien las cosas, el resto esta excelente.

Te dejo mi codigo que no creo que sirva pero tengo los resultados de cada operacion:

```
let condensales = 4
let precio_arroz = 3
let precio_gamba = 13.5

let cant_arroz = condensales * 0.5 / 4  //-->0.5
let cant_gambas = condensales * 0.25 / 4 //--> 0.25

let cost_arroz= cant_arroz * precio_arroz //-->1.5
let cost_gamba = cant_gambas * precio_gamba //-->3.375

let total = cost_arroz + cost_gamba //-->4.875
```

Comment: gracias, no sé cómo no me di cuenta, muchas gracias